# My code runs fine but breaks while in a game loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unhandled-exception

The code below is able to run fine in the debugger but ends up failing to print anything after the while(incorrect) loop as commented at the bottom. Upon finishing the function of the code or guessing everything the code crashes and takes you to the runtime error in a file named memcpy.asm. From my research people often get this file to only be associated with being missing. I do remember that my code was working all the way through on an earlier version before adding the hint array and going into visual studio's tools->options->Debugger->Symbols and checking "Microsoft Symbol Servers", since my initial run after checking it I've unchecked it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome to my Word Scramble!\nYou can quit at anytime by typing 'quit' and get a hint by typing 'hint' though this halfs your points!\n";
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    bool gameOn = true;
    int score = 0;

    while (gameOn)
    {

        std::string word[] = { "programming","saturn","helpful","terrible","college" };
        std::string hint[] = { "Another word is coding","A planet in our solar system","to be of use","Just the worst","School for grown ups" };

        for (int i = 0;i < word->size();i++) 
        {
            std::string jumble = word[i];
            int length = jumble.size();

            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
            {
                int index1 = rand() % length;
                int index2 = rand() % length;
                char temp = jumble[index1];
                jumble[index1] = jumble[index2];
                jumble[index2] = temp;
            }

            std::cout << "Here is the word you'll be unscrambling!\t--" << jumble << "--\n";
            int guesses = 1;
            int pointReward = 100*length;
            std::string guess;
            bool incorrect = true;

            while (incorrect)
            {
                std::cin >> guess;
                if (guess == "quit") 
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                else if (guess == "hint")
                {
                    pointReward /= 2;
                    std::cout << "Your score for this round has been reduced by half, Here is your hint:";
                    std::cout << hint[i] << std::endl;
                }
                else if (guess == word[i])
                {
                    incorrect = false;
                    int roundPoints = pointReward / guesses;
                    score += roundPoints;
                    std::cout << "Correct!!! You get " << roundPoints << " Points!\n\nYour total score is " << score << std::endl;
                }
                else if (guess!="hint"&&guess!="")
                {
                    guesses++;
                    std::cout << "That wasn't quite it, I believe in you!\n";
                }
                std::cout << "right after else if state\n";
            }
            std::cout << "right after incorrect loop";
        }
        std::cout << "Anything after this point won't print";
        gameOn = false;
    }
    std::cout << "Your final score was " << score << "!";
    std::cout << "\tThanks For Playing My First C++ Game!";
    return 0;
}
```

The consoles error message for the code is to cryptic for me to understand what the problem is:

```
'Word Jumble.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'
Exception thrown at 0x509146FE (vcruntime140d.dll) in Word Jumble.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.
Unhandled exception at 0x509146FE (vcruntime140d.dll) in Word Jumble.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.
```

I did some quick research but the "Access violation reading location..." is bad code but I see nothing wrong logic wise.

Comment: Access violation reading location... usually comes from trying to read beyond the bounds of an array, which is how Swordfish found your bug so fast ;)

Comment: @Mars No, Swordfish was lazy, played the word guessing game and looked at the call stack after the crash ^^

Comment: Work (play) smarter not harder? haha

Comment: @Swordfish I included the compile error, Why did you have to run the code still? So it would take you to the line the error happened at? Also, if that were the case my compiler dumped me in a file I didn't even know existed. What did you do to find the error?

Comment: "So it would take you to the line the error happened at?" Yes. "What did you do to find the error?" I built your code in a debug configuration and ran it with the debugger attached, entered a few words. Then my debugger brought me to a line in some standard library include file. I looked at the call stack and went back to the last line executed in your code before the exception was thrown: `std::string jumble = word[i];`

Comment: The only thing in that line that could have lead to an access violation is reading from `word` with an invalid index. Next I looked at where `i` comes from and found `for (int i = 0; i < word->size(); i++)` remembered that `word` is an array and realized that `word->size()` is the same as `word[0].size()`, which is obviously not what one wants when iterating through an array of size `std::size(word)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`word->size()` gives you the length of the string `word[0]`. What you want, though, is the size of the array `word[]`. Use `std::size(word)`.